# Show that if $\Sigma$ $a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\Sigma$ $a^2_n$ also converges. Is this still true if $\Sigma$ $a_n$ converges conditionally?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Do I use a convergence test to solve this? The definition of converges absolutely is $\Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty}$|$a_n$|

Comment: It does not look as you tried much. What about $a_n=\frac{1}{f(n)}$, with $f(n)$ being a slowly increasing function?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Since $a_n\to 0$, there is an $N$ s.t.
$$|a_n|<1$$
if $n>N$, and thus
$$|a_n|^2<|a_n|$$
when $n>N$.

Answer (score 0):

No,  $\sum\frac {(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$ converges conditionally, but it is well-know that $\sum \frac 1n$ does not.